# LDAPs and memberOf attribute in Ansible AWX

Tags: active-directory, ansible, ldap, ldap-query, ansible-awx

I want to connect my AWX instance via LDAPs to our MS AD, but where/and how to install the CA root-trusted certificate?

Furthermore, I want to grant a login only from users of a certain group (memberOf), where I do not know how to deposit this attribute

Comment: For everyone interested how to solve the second point:

LDAP Group Search:
[
 "MemberOf=CN=awxallow,OU=Gruppen,OU=foo,OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=local",
 "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
 "(objectFilter=MemberOf)"
]

LDAP Require Group:
CN=awxallow,OU=Gruppen,OU=foo,OU=foo,DC=domain,DC=local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your AWX instance in docker.
Install the certificates on your machine where you're running docker on. During the installation provide the path to root certs (`inventory` file in `installer` dir):

```
ca_trust_dir=/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
```

If you have AWX already installed and don't want to re-deploy - install certificates to `awx_web` and `awx_task` containers.

Copy cert and go to the container, e.g.

```
docker cp cert.crt awx_task:/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/your_org.crt
docker exec -it awx_task /bin/bash
```

Finally install the cert:

```
update-ca-trust enable
update-ca-trust extract
```

Repeat for the second container (awx_web)

Comment: I believe this would work for running the containers with docker, but not when running inside a Kubernetes pod. I had to do this to make it work. https://groups.google.com/g/awx-project/c/p4sKMYJr6gk